# Nested layouts with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

The Tk documentation [says](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) (last section) that nested layouts can be achieved using `tk.frame`. 
The following small example is not working as expected, instead of:

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('250x100')

# first level, window as parent
tk.Label(window, text='Choose file:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Button(window, text='Browse ...').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
fr = tk.Frame(window).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

# nested, frame as parent
tk.Entry(fr).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Entry(fr).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.mainloop()
```

it produces:

[image]

The real UI is much more complex, so I really want to use nested grids instead of one grid with multiple columns.

Comment: Read [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759), your `fr` is `None` therefore the parent is `root`.

Comment: It would have taken just a few seconds to verify that `fr` is not set to what you think it is.

Comment: Bryan - you are right, I am just too used to statically typed languages. But why Python is not throwing an error in such case?

Comment: @Mikhail: because there is no error to report. It's perfectly valid to do what you did, it's just that what you expect to happen and what is documented to happen are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `tkinter` does not produce intuitive results if you create an object and grid at once. This should give you the same result with the documentation:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('250x100')

# first level, window as parent
tk.Button(window, text='Browse ...').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
tk.Label(window, text='Choose file:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
fr = tk.Frame(window)
fr.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

# nested, frame as parent
entry1 = tk.Entry(fr)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
entry2 = tk.Entry(fr)
entry2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not so much that "it doesn't produce good results", it's that it doesn't produce _intuitive_ results.

Comment: Oh, I got it - `fr` was not the frame object. I wonder why python accepts such code without an error

Comment: ***"tkinter does not produce good results if you create an object and grid at once."***: Did you have any reference about this.

Comment: @Mikhail ***"I wonder why python accepts such code without an error"***: It's the default, you can change it by calling `tk.NoDefaultRoot()`